# change the list option based on the selection type

Tags: theming, forms, nodes

In a form, user have an option to choose the submission type. Based on the selected submission type, user should get an option to choose sub-type. Please let me know how this is done in Drupal 7. Please suggest a module.
[image]

If user select e-book, sub-type should change to case:1 (see image)
If user select e-project, sub-type should change to case:2
If user select e-lab manual, sub-type should change to case:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module...

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. You can, for example, define
>   a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser"
>   checkbox is checked.

See below image displayed in project page which suits your requirement.. Hope above module solves your problem..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is taxonomy term based, try using [Simple hierarchial select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs). Details from project page:

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.
>   The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed filter.
>
> This module has been inspired by Hierarchical select but is much simpler.

It provides a field widget that can force deepest level selection, so your nested terms are fully utilized.